# Can CommonJS be used without webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

I have a js library that I would like to turn into a CommonJS module. Once I do that, I would like to access it through global variable by including it via a script tag in a legacy project that is *not using Webpack* or any modern build tools.

Is this possible? Or is Webpack in anyway required for using CommonJS?

I would like to end up with something like this, where this legacy project uses CommonJS but does not include Webpack in any way to bundle or manage dependencies whatsoever.

```
<script scr="lib/common.js"></script>
<script scr="lib/my-module.js"></script>
<script>
    // Older projects run it using jQuery. Newer ones will load on angular.run()
    $('document').ready(myModule);
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure how to proceed, however browsers certainly do not natively understand CJS. You'd need to work around that somehow. Perhaps see how popular libraries that can be consumed both as global scripts and modules do it?

Comment: I would include CommonJS in the project. What I don't want to do is modify the project to use *Webpack* to do any bundling or managing dependencies.

Comment: There are other options like gulp or grunt, but ultimately you're going to need something to bring all your files together. `require` isn't natively available in the browser.

Comment: OK but requireJS works without any build tools like gulp or webpack right? My question is wether commonJS modules can be used without setting up a build tool the way requireJS can work without one.